# Fatal error during installation of VS 2017 Community

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've been trying to install Visual Studio 2017 Community edition for about a week, but I keep getting the following errors.

> Message Id: 1310 Message Details: Error writing to file:
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll.
>
> Message Id: 1310 Message Details: Error writing to file:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.PerformanceTools.Detours.dll.

I'm trying to install the desktop applications workload, or whatever it's called.

I've searched around on the internet, and tried a few things. Including 
- Installing all pending windows updates. 
- Uninstalling the VS installer, running a clean up utility, and rebooting.
- Trying to manually run the msi that is failing (they still fail).
- Uninstalling every SQL server thing on the machine.

I haven't been able to find anything on the internet, that solved my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to get your machine fixed first.  Run chkdsk.exe at a minimum, disable the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: @HansPassant ran chkdsk.exe and found no problems.  I'll try turning off anti-malware.

Comment: Still failed, even with all anti-virus  and anti-malware turned off.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think what might have happened is you might have some older versions of DLLs in place that you don't have permission to overwrite. Please uninstall VS 2017 again, then manually delete `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0` and/or `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0` then try the installation again.

   This is assuming you don't need any pre-existing stuff in those directories.

   The detours dll for example would be in something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies`
2. It can be folder permissions related. Do you have permission to write to the directories you need? Try running the installer "as administrator", and make sure the user you are installing as will have the permissions to write to that folder and the program files folders. Maybe try installing in another directory.
3. Download the installer fresh again, it could be corrupted.
4. Make sure you did not run out of disk space.
5. Since there is a SQL Server DLL conflicting, maybe try uninstalling SQL server, clearing out directories manually that contain that DLL, then reinstall.

One of these things should help but it's hard for me to be sure without access to the environment. Good luck! I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I uninstalled VS 2017, I've deleted the directory, and I've searched the PC for the offending dlls.  I ran the installer as admin, so I'm not sure why I wouldn't have permissions to write the dll.  And I have plenty of disk space.  I'm going to try running the installer again, and see if it works.

Comment: Installation still failed.

Comment: is this just a PC that you own or a company-owned domain PC?

Comment: my personal home PC

Comment: I mean, one way to fix it easily would be to reinstall windows fresh. Is that an option?

Comment: That seems a bit extreme, just to install a single application.